# Generate string from table cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, string

I am using Excel 2008 for Mac. I would like to have a cell generate a string based on the contents of the other cells on the same row.

For example, say I have the following table headers:

bob, weave, nip, tuck

And the next row (or could be any subsequent row) are multiplier numbers, for example:

2, 3, 1, 2

I would like the last cell on that row to generate a string based on the counts in each cell, the result would be:

"bob, bob, weave, weave, weave, nip, tuck, tuck"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

pick a cell and enter:

```
=REPT(A1 & ", ",A2) & REPT(B1 & ", ",B2) & REPT(C1 & ", ",C2) & REPT(D1 & ", ",D2)
```

Comment: This almost yields the requested output, except it will leave a dangling comma on the last item (yes I know, that sounds pretty picky).  But it seems pretty complicated to put a conditional of some sort on inserting the comma.

Comment: @Electro-Bunny  The trailing **comma** can be removed by using the **LEFT()** function.